# Need help making the catgroups show in the inner navigation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

[image]My website is theboutiqueconnect.com. My code is only showing one Catgroup term in the div and the rest under trying to accomplish the look of my old site brandingang.com

```
    <div class="header__navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__navigation-inner">
      <ul class="header__navigation-category1">
        <li>
@foreach ($all_categories as $catGroup)
          @if ($catGroup->subGroups->count())
            @php
            @endphp
            <li>
              <a href="{{ route('categoryGrp.browse', $catGroup->slug) }}">
                @if ($catGroup->logoImage && Storage::exists($catGroup->logoImage->path))
                  <img src="{{ $catGroup->name }}">
                @else
                @endif

                <span>{{ $catGroup->name }}</span>
              </a>

                <div class="row">
                  @foreach ($catGroup->subGroups as $subGroup)
                      @php
                        $cat_counter = 0; //Reset the counter
                      @endphp
                      
                          @foreach ($subGroup->categories as $cat)
                            @php
                              $cat_counter++; //Increase the counter value by 1
                            @endphp
                          @endforeach
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  @endforeach
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          @endif
        @endforeach
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: what is under `$catGroup->subGroups`?

Comment: What are you expected as a result post and sketch or example? Can't understand your coding

Comment: added image at the top

Comment: so you want jut to print side by side and no sub navigation? Isn't it?

Comment: at first the nav menu initially had a drop down with the categories in it. I deleted that to get the catgroup to show. I have it showing the the main categories but it only shows on in the top bar and the rest in the white section. For some reason its not adding the remainder of the categories in the div

Comment: Show me your data array `$all_categories`

Comment: if you look at my page theboutiqueconnect i have reverted it back to the original

Comment: i can keep the mega menu but instead of the drop down for categories i just want the terms inside of the category drop-down to be in the navigation

Comment: If you take a look at my old web page brandingang.com the nav bar its how i would want it. On theboutiqueconnect.comim trying to list the terms inside of the category drop down on the nav bar

Comment: Post the data array.